# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

Hi I am trying to open a fragment when clicking on item of a grid view but its showing the error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView. please help me anyone.

Screen frag:

```
 public class Screen extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen, container, false);
        int[] text = {R.string.temp, R.string.weight, R.string.len, R.string.time, R.string.area, R.string.vol, R.string.store, R.string.prsure, R.string.sound, R.string.ene, R.string.mag, R.string.img};
        int[] imgId = {R.drawable.temperature, R.drawable.food, R.drawable.resize, R.drawable.circular, R.drawable.pie, R.drawable.chemistry, R.drawable.database, R.drawable.blood, R.drawable.sound, R.drawable.energy, R.drawable.magnet, R.drawable.images};

        GridView grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        Custom_Grid adapter = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            adapter = new Custom_Grid(getContext(), text, imgId);
        }

        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Fragment fragment;
                FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new Temperature();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new Weight();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new Length();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        fragment = new Time();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        fragment = new Area();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;

  }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

CustomGrid:

```
public class Custom_Grid extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    private final int[] text;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public Custom_Grid(Context c, int[] text, int[] Imageid) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.text=text;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return text.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(text[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        return grid;
    }
}
```

mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Screen scr = new Screen();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.sun,scr);
        ft.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 00:26:40.940 5117-5117/com.example.cherrypandu.uc E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.cherrypandu.uc, PID: 5117
03-11 00:26:40.940 5117-5117/com.example.cherrypandu.uc E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
03-11 00:26:40.940 5117-5117/com.example.cherrypandu.uc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:469)
03-11 00:26:40.940 5117-5117/com.example.cherrypandu.uc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
03-11 00:26:40.940 5117-5117/com.example.cherrypandu.uc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
```

Comment: you are replacing the grid layout to another fragment, replace the Gridlayout fragment to another fragment not the xml.

Comment: I have tried that one but showing another type of error

Comment: okay let me check and work on it.

Comment: then it showing error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00bf by trying on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are try to perform `setText()` with the `String` int id resource instead of retrieve the `String` object. You also not instatiate the `View` correctly.
Your adapter should looks something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        textView.setText(mContext.getString(text[position]));
        imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
    } else {
        grid = convertView;
    }
    return grid;
}
```

In addition I highly recommend you to use the patern of `ViewHolder` in your adaper. You can read about it here: [ViewHolder](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving you the hint, because you did not post the all xml files over here.

In your MainActivity XML add below frame layout on which view fragments will be switch/added:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

add this method to MainActivity.java to switch framgent:

```
 public void switchContentWithBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,
                        fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

addToBackStack(null) will add the current fragment to backstack.

get the instance of MainActivity on OnAttach() in your FragmentScreen:

```
 MainActivity mActivity;

  @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
    }
```

To Switch Fragment call the method by passing object of Fragment you want to show:

```
mActivity.switchContentWithBackStack(mFragment);
```

If this help then accept, if you have queries then let me know.

Comment: where to pass the code mActivity.switchContentWithBackStack(mFragment); in switch case of my screen fragment.

Comment: can you explain what you not getting?

Answer (score 0):

Screen Fragment :

Changes in onItemClick of Gridview

```
public class Screen extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen, container, false);
        int[] text = {R.string.temp, R.string.weight, R.string.len, R.string.time, R.string.area, R.string.vol, R.string.store, R.string.prsure, R.string.sound, R.string.ene, R.string.mag, R.string.img};
        int[] imgId = {R.drawable.temperature, R.drawable.food, R.drawable.resize, R.drawable.circular, R.drawable.pie, R.drawable.chemistry, R.drawable.database, R.drawable.blood, R.drawable.sound, R.drawable.energy, R.drawable.magnet, R.drawable.images};

        GridView grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        Custom_Grid adapter = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            adapter = new Custom_Grid(getContext(), text, imgId);
        }

        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Fragment fragment;
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new Temperature();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sun,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new Weight();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sun,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new Length();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sun,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        fragment = new Time();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sun,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        fragment = new Area();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sun,fragment).commit();
                        break;

  }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```